# Clone of production environment for tests in VMware

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I'm trying to find a way to make a quick copy of a large number of virtual machines in order to use them to test new features for a productive environment.

For example, the VMware has a product "Site Recovery Manager". There is the possibility of creating a test environment for virtual machines, using the "Recovery Plan Testing". In a few minutes the system launches snapshot from second physical storage and creates a complete copy of all virtual machines, with VLANs in VRF, starting them and listen for heartbeat.

But this is not the best idea, use this option for long-term use of the test environment as a lab environment. Sadly.

Is there such a product or solution that will allow to clone a large number of virtual machines (> 2TB) in an up-to-date state for carrying out tests in an isolated environment?

My conf:

```
2 vCenter 6.5.1 in Linked-mode.
2 storages with vmware SRA compatibility. 
2 different clusters.
```

Comment: `But this is not the best idea, use this option for long-term use of the test environment as a lab environment.` - Why not?

Comment: If you need to run disaster recovery failover and your Recovery Test in online - you should cleaning up "plan testing" before "distaster failover". In some cases cleanup can hang waiting for another tasks and there is no option to make a "force cleanup" first.  In this case, it may turn out that failover during an accident can take much longer than necessary and add more actions. I'm not sure that I'm right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your storage system supports ROW or COW snapshots that can be mounted R/W, that would be one great option. You could instantly "clone" an entire LUN at a time and to refresh you test environment, just blow away the snapshot mount and mount the latest snapshot. You still need to provide your own network solution. I would normally have a second VMware stack that has identical (or close to) configs and put the VM vLANs behind a PAT (port address translation). Test and Prod should not communicate anyway and this minimizes the required changes to prod in order to support test.

Comment: Are you talking about a KVM/QEMU scenario? as VMware doesn't natively support ROW/COW based volumes or have any real guest IP stack operations such as NATing.